# How can I trace Database operations with opentelemetry in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, jaeger, open-telemetry

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project, let's call it `projectA`.

ProjectA connects to a MySQL database.

Project A simply does this:

- get a request
- then make a query to the connected MySQL database
- then return response to request

I want to measure time spent for database operation and send result to Jaeger.

For http requests opentelemetry automatically measure time spent for request and send results to jaeger.

How can I do the same thing with opentelemetry for database operations?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jaeger but it seems that it can automatically gather data from database operation in `span`? See [this comment](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/issues/1944#issuecomment-559116290) and I saw there's some others' screenshot, and can trace mysql operations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable SQL Client instrumentation when configuring your tracer provider.

```
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSqlClientInstrumentation()
            .AddConsoleExporter()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Here's the official documentation: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient#readme

Comment: yusuf uses MySql. SqlClient is for Sql Server.